# How to declare and instantiate N-tuples?

Tags: c#, tuples

I've checked through the posts on here and none that I've found seems to address my specific issue.  At the time of posting this I had misread the MSDN category, on N-tuples, and couldn't see an obvious reason for my N-Tuple not working.  I'm trying to make a tuple of N size for the first time, and am getting errors when I try to assign values.  I think I just have the syntax off by a bit.

My Tuple:

```
public Tuple<float, float, float, float, float, float, float, 
     Tuple<float, float, float, float, float, float, float, Tuple<float>>> 
     CollisionTuple = new Tuple<float, float, float, float, float, float, 
     float, Tuple<float, float, float, float, float, float, float, Tuple<float>>>
     (0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, Tuple<float, float, float, float, float, float, float>
     (0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, Tuple<float>(0)));
```

So, which part of my syntax is off?  Everything before assigning a value to the tuple doesn't return an error.

**Update:**
I just `overloaded` the method and went with an `array` for that collision detect.

Comment: Did you try adding `new` before the inner tuple declarations?

Comment: You're missing a couple of `new`s. (Also: is there any way you could simplify this variable? It's **very** confusing.)

Comment: yeah, had tried adding `new` on Microsoft's tuple page they don't have new for the N-tuples.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd383325(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: Oh they're using the `Tuple.Create` method for the larger `Tuples`. I'll give that a shot.

Comment: @ZeroPhase Yes they do. `var primes = new Tuple<Int32, Int32, Int32, Int32, Int32, Int32, Int32, Tuple<Int32>> (2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, new Tuple<Int32>(19));`

Comment: @Patashu adding `new`gives 3 errors.  I think I have to use 2 `Tuple.create` and tack the variable from them on the end for `tuples` over 8.

Comment: Why would you do such a monstrosity?? Can you please give me one real-life example that wouldn't violate at least one OOP principle?

Comment: @walther I'm setting up collision for trees, and the last map is layed out in such a way that the 8-Tuple I had used for all of the other maps won't work for selecting points.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@dlev's answer is correct. However, I'd recommend creating a new type for this, to make your code much more readable:

```
class CollisionTuple : Tuple<float, float, float, float, float, float, float, 
                         Tuple<float, float, float, float, float, float, float, 
                           Tuple<float>>>
{
    CollisionTuple(float f1, float f2, ..., float f15) 
        : Tuple<(7 type arguments...)>(f1, f2, ..., f7, 
              new Tuple<(7 type arguments again...)>(f8, ..., f14,
                  new Tuple<float>(f15))))
    {
    }
}
```

That way, you can insantiate it like this:

```
// where the class is used:
CollisionTuple collTup = new CollisionTuple(0, 0, (etc...), 0);
```

If you know that you're often going to initialize it with zeros, you can even create a default constructor that does that for you:

```
// inside the class, with the other constructor still defined:
CollisionTuple() : CollisionTuple(0, 0, (etc...), 0) { };
```

which makes usage even easier:

```
var collisionTuple = new CollisionTuple();
```

Voilá! All those messy generics and counting arguments are just gone (or at least dusted under the rug...) and you can focus on the important parts of your code =)

Comment: would making 2 additional `Tuples` with `Tuple.Create`, and tacking them on at the end of the `Tuple` holding the other `Tuples` work as well?  Your way definitely seems ideal.  The thing is I only need this once, and I'd have to rewrite the rest of the code using the `8-Tuple`.

Comment: I'm not sure - and I can't test it since I'm on Ubuntu on this computer... But have a look at [the docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd383325.aspx) - if it's possible, it's probably stated there somewhere.

Comment: @ZeroPhase: On second thought - [no, it doesn't seem like you can](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee835388.aspx). I'd do the abstraction anyway, though, just to get that hideous generic garble-soup out of my face...

Answer (score 3):

You're actually really close, you just forgot a couple of `new`s, and one of the `Tuple<float>` type arguments. This works:

```
public Tuple<float, float, float, float, float, float, float, 
 Tuple<float, float, float, float, float, float, float, Tuple<float>>> 
 CollisionTuple = new Tuple<float, float, float, float, float, float, 
 float, Tuple<float, float, float, float, float, float, float, Tuple<float>>>
 (0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, new Tuple<float, float, float, float, float, float, float, Tuple<float>>
 (0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, new Tuple<float>(0)));
```

As I mentioned in my comment, though, you should really try to simplify this, perhaps by creating a new type to encapsulate whatever the heck is going on here. The fact you need to debug *the instantiation* of this object is a bad sign.

Comment: Yeah, this isn't a good application of Tuples. In theory they're infinite, ordered sets. In C# they're more like C structs with ItemX instead of the normal field names. Whatever you're doing should be done using some other structure (perhaps an ordered list, or an ordered list of float arrays).

Comment: Thanks, I must've missed place one of the `new`s when going above an `8-Tuple`

Comment: @dlev Yeah, I think I'll just use `Tuple.Create`, and place the later tuples in through a variable.